# How do I get the user IDs of all the members in my discord server using python and discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to get a list containing the user ID of every member in my discord server. I have turned on the privelege intents required, and my bot is only in one server, my personal server.

I tried looking through the API documentation and the closest I could find was guild.members. However, members doesnt have a method that allows you to get the ID of a user.

My code looks like this right now:

```
@bot.command()
async def Test1(ctx): # Called it Test1 just so I can play around and try and figure it out
  print(ctx.guild.member_count) # returns the right amount in integer format
  for i in range(ctx.guild.member_count):
    print(ctx.members.id) # members doesn't have id attribute
```

Sorry if this is a really simple problem to solve, this is my first time working with API documentions and discord bots.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.member_count` only gives you the member count of the guild.
If you want to go through all members you should try [`guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild%20members#discord.Guild.members).
First you get the guild object with [`Client.get_guild()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild) and then loop through that to get the member.

```py
guild = bot.get_guild(ctx.guild.id)
for member in guild.members:
  print(member.id)
```

Comment: All right, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
@bot.command()
async def memberid(ctx:commands.Context):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    guild = ctx.guild
    with open("memberids.txt", "w") as file:
        for member in guild.members:
            file.write(str(member.id)+"\n")
    await ctx.send("Memeber IDs sucessfully collected!",delete_after=10)
```

This will create a text file containing the ids. To read the file I created this command:

```
@bot.command()
async def members(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    with open("memberids.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            true_id = int(line.strip())
            await ctx.send(f"<@{true_id}>",delete_after=10)
```

Here you read the ids from the file, you remove the "\n" with "line.strip()" and create an integer out of the string. Then you send member mentions to the command executer using the ids. The "await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)"  and "delete_after=10" are just "decorations" you can leave them out if you want. The first one deletes the trigger message, the second one deletes the bot's response after 10 seconds.